# Can the identity of a person in Nigeria be confirmed?

Tags: authentication

I need to find out if a person is who they say they are. Can that be confirmed?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can lead someone to the truth, but you cannot make them believe. It is not possible to reliably verify someone's identity (who you are not related to or have legal proceedings agains) across countries that reliably, and even then I wonder if it is helpful in your situation.

Comment: I empathize with you deeply, and am so sorry your husband fell for the scam. Please get your banker, lawyer, and psychologist ready to help you.

Comment: It's sad to say that these particular types of "love" scams are so common that the U.S. State Department has set up a page specifically to educate potential victims about them :  https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/emergencies/scams/dating.html   Note that one of the common techniques specifically listed is the "U.S. citizen who can't get back" scam.   Maybe the official warning from the federal government that, yes, this is almost certainly a scam might help make some kind of impact in your husband's mind. (Maybe.) In any case, I feel for you, and for him.

Answer (score 12):

### This is probably a scam attempt. You need to sever all communication

Forgive my bluntness. You appear to be an older person. Your age-range is a *primary target* for [Nigerian 419 scammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam). Why? You're in prime retirement age, and likely have a 401k plus other savings ripe for the picking.

Please note that ***nobody*** will to start a real relationship with a random person out of the blue. ***Nobody*** will fall in love with you after a week or two: they are either a scammer, a spy, mentally-ill, a mix, or all of those. They ***always*** have ulterior motives. There are ***really funny*** ways to screw with these malcontents, but you need to be completely aware of this fact before starting. Something tells me your husband isn't aware.

Keep in mind that "Falling in love with you after a really short duration" is a classic hallmark of a spy, or scammer. Does your husband work for the defense industry? Has he in the past? Has he ever had a security clearance? Have *you*?

If the answer is "Yes," you need to report it to the government or you will completely lose either clearance. If the answer is "no," he's just being scammed.

---

### Please take note

- If they are offering to send you money, they are lying.
- If they ask you for money, they are lying.
- If they start going *"Praise Jesus! He's led me to you so I can give you money,"* they are lying.
- If they quote all the right scripture, **they are still lying**.
- If they need your bank account information for any reason, they are lying.
- If they need money for an operation, they are lying.
- If they need money for a business investment, they are lying.
- If they need your PayPal info, they are lying.
- If they need you to do something at Western Union, they are lying.
- If they provide Linked-In pages showing the company they work at, don't believe them. (Thanks, [Fiasco Labs](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6585/fiasco-labs)). **In fact, don't visit any of their websites!**
- If they send you a check to cash, they are lying and you'll be in trouble. (Thanks, halfinformed)
- Did I mention they are lying?

Assume the above is true regardless of their nationality. More than likely, you're communicating with someone who claims to be in Nigeria. Maybe he's a prince? Maybe he's offering to split a few hundred million / millions of pounds with you.

**Don't believe him/her/it/them, unless you want to lose everything.**

---

### Additional Important Information

**[Rui F Riberio](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/92077/rui-f-ribeiro)** has offered some very important information that I believe should be considered:

> If the 100USD was a bank transfer, they already know the bank account, they probably know too many details about the common passwords, parents name, etc...close the account, move the money to another bank.
>
> I would also handle the computer as potentially compromised. One of the photos *[fake photos that are really executables; buffer overflows in image parsers]* / messages could have helped install a virus that is monitoring the computer. As an cautionary tale someone from my family got defrauded to the tune of 80k, and the bank order transfer came by fax when he was travelling to another continent. Due to the timing, we suspect they got the info from his own emails. Luckily enough the forgery of the signature was not even close to his, and due to Europe laws, he managed to cancel the transfer.
>
> The investigation also found out that at the end of the day, the guy pretending to be him was calling from a voIP account in Indonesia. The guy actually called the bank impersonating him to demand that the transfer was put back in order

---

### Using Psychology against your husband

At this point, your husband is likely too psychologically invested to give up and admit he's been scammed. Admitting that he's been fooled is much harder than coming to terms with the truth. He doesn't want to be seen as a fool, nor does he want to feel ashamed, so he keeps it going in the "hopes" that he'll be right, even if deep-down inside, he knows he's wrong about it.

Some people enjoy hurting others for no good reason, preying on basic human psychology, etc. Those are extreme sociopaths. Only a complete nutter would even desire to do something like this. They really, really don't care about either of you. All they want is your money, and they'll do anything to get it.

### This is probably a scam attempt. You need to sever all communication

Comment: Also, if they provide Linked-In pages showing the company they work at, take it and any information contained within with a grain of cyanide... At least you won't miss your bank account afterwards.

Comment: I am 47 yrs old but it's my husband they have attached themself to thru facebook then thru text messaging on a app called hangout. They tell him they love him and they send him pics of a woman and her family but will not call him. And when they did call the number was from Nigeria and it was a mobile phone. I looked it up. I don't know how to give him the proof he wants showing they are not the woman they claim to be

Comment: Show your husband this post. Also, they'll take his money and his heart if he keeps this up. @MelissaTheriot The age range for them would be 40+

Comment: Is there away to search a picture? I have a name also, but I think it is someone else's identity. I google searched the name and have pictures that are posted like that but I can access her facebook. She won't accept me

Comment: Here are some example communications: http://www.419eater.com/

Comment: You can probably drag and drop the picture into Google image search and find the same one used before.

Comment: This is far more serious than that...people have lost thousand of dollars with this Nigerians scams, and the few that actually went to Nigeria had serious problems. For now, they are asking 100USD to know the details of the bank account, next they will need your husband passport/ID for some "official" reason.

Comment: @Mark Buffalo  Only one thing I might add to your nice comprehensive list:  If they send you a check, money order, or other financial document and tell you they are in a desperate circumstance and need you to cash it and send part of the funds along to them, they are lying. Check cashing schemes  have become such a hot form of fraud in the past few years.  They are devastatingly effective because the mark thinks the person's claim, whatever it is, must be legit; the scammer in Nigeria actually sends a check, and the bank seems to accept it.  Then the mark immediately sends money overseas...

Comment: ... and then likely never hear from their correspondent again.  And a few days later the mark's bank calls: when the purportedly legit check or money order was actually processed by the international bank system's machinations it was found to be a forgery or draw on insufficient funds. The mark/victim is now on the hook to repay the sum of that check or order to the bank.  And since he or she immediately used the funds from the redemption and sent them to Nigeria/wherever, he or she is massively screwed.

Comment: @MelissaTheriot If the 100USD was a bank transfer, they already know the bank account, they probably know too much details about the common passwords, parents name, etc...close the account, move the money to another bank.

Comment: I would also handle the computer as potentially compromised. One of the photos/messages could have a virus that is monitoring the computer. As an cautionary tale someone from my family got defrauded to the tune of 80k, and the bank order transfer came by fax when he was travelling to another continent. Due to the timing, we suspect they got the info from his own emails. Luckily enough the forgery of the signature was not even close to his, and due to Europe laws, he managed to cancel the transfer.

Comment: The investigation also found out that at the end of the day, the guy pretending to be him was calling from a voIP account in Indonesia. The guy actually called the bank impersonating him to demand that the transfer was put back in order...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I added your experience to my post and credited you. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

They're probably not who they say they are.  Don't send them money.

If you're actually serious, and you're a U.S. citizen, you can try to investigate the State Department's [Notarial and Authentication Services of Consular Officers](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/judicial/authentication-of-documents/notarial-and-authentication-services-consular-officers.html).

Comment: I am very serious. This person has convinced my husband they are a real woman that is from Dallas Texas but is in Nigeria and trying to get back to the states. She claims to be in love with him and I have told him its a scam but he is having a hard time believing it. He already sent $100

Comment: Get hold of your bank and any other financial institutions you are involved with and tell them that your husband's a live one on the line with a con-artist and has swallowed it hook, line and sinker. This is an intervention type situation that needs to be nipped in the bud before much more than $100 escapes out the door. Cons tell a convincing story and many's the mark out there that finds out too late that faith based decision making can be fatal in many ways. The family lawyer, if you have one needs to get a heads up as well.

Comment: Since they're claiming to be a U.S. citizen trying to get back to the U.S., it should, if they're being truthful, be simple for them to visit the Consular offices during one of their normal trips to the Embassy.  If they spin excuses, then they're not trying to get back, they're not U.S. citizens, or both.

Answer (score 3):

You mention in a comment that they sent a picture of "themselves".

You may be able to find evidence that they are not who they say they are:

1. Visit https://images.google.com
2. Click the camera icon to the right of the search box
3. Choose "Upload an Image"
4. Upload your image

For further help and alternatives, you can read this page: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en

This may bring up some useful information such as:

- the original source of the image (the scammer probably obtained this image from a public web page)
- other people discussing this scam

You may also consider reporting this scam to Facebook.  They may close the account which would stop that channel of communication at least.

Comment: +1 for one way of possibly proving it's a scam.

Comment: I would do this check too, but realize that a smart scammer would use an original image (and even could have been in the states at some point of time).

Answer (score 0):

The only distinguishing feature of this woman is that she loves your husband (the Dallas point was arbitrary from the beginning).  It's impossible to prove that.  If you want to come close to proving it, he could just buy her a ticket to the states instead of giving cash.  You will see her intentions then, expensively, but that answers your question.

Comment: Of course, I would never recommend this since it is most likely a scam, but notice that every other posted answer can only prove the negative.  And, sorry, I am trying to ignore the emotions which are surely involved here.